# Problem run web application asp.net mvc 3 under iis 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, iis, iis-7, msdeploy

I deployed my asp.net mvc 3 project under IIS 7 (Windows 7). Project contain attach *.mdf DB file in App_Data folder. First I got following error:

*Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed.*

I removed it so change connection string in my web.config file - remove **user instanse=true** and in *Application Pool -> Addvanced Setting -> Process Model -> Load User Profile* set value TRUE and then I got next error:
**CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\assign\App_Data\AssignmentDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.**

my connection string is

```
<add name="AssignmentDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.AssignmentDBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.AssignmentDBModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.AssignmentDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\AssignmentDB.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I don't known how resolve this problem..((
someone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

The account you're using to connect to the database (specified in the connection string) doesn't have a CREATE DATABASE permission. You need to grant this permission in order to be able to create database.

You can just execute sql command (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569.aspx) or use Enterprise Manager to grant permission.

The user you need to grant the permission to is the one specified in the connection string or the account your website runs under if you're using integrated security.

Comment: thank you. But my sql server don't find this DB file because it attached to project